# When to pay attention to NULL values in SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null

I know that you should not use the clause `NOT IN` when you have `NULL` values you're trying to compare to. Also, an arithmetic operation involving a `NULL` returns `NULL`.

However in other situations `NULL` values don't cause issues, for instance, there is no problem with operations such as `MAX`, `MIN`…

So, what are situations/operations where one should be aware of `NULL` values?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a problem with arithmetic operations. Have you tried `0+null`?

Comment: This might help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html

Comment: @forpas yes there is! I edited my post...

Comment: @AlessioCantarella . . . The answer is that you should always be aware of `NULL` values.  The are legitimate values in SQL and if your code is not `NULL`-safe, then you should KNOW that the columns have no `NULL` values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have just edited the question! 

Answer (score 2):

You should always pay attention to `NULL` values.  They are valid values for all SQL types (or almost all, maybe there are a handful of exceptions somewhere).  They can also be produced in the course of normal query operations (via outer joins, for instance).

What do they effect?  A close approximation is that all functions and operators are affected by `NULL` values; most return `NULL` if any values are `NULL`.  There ARE exceptions of course.

In addition, `NULL` values cause `JOIN`s to fail, unless special care is taken.

Unless you rigorously define all columns as `NOT NULL` and avoid outer joins, you should always be thinking about how `NULL` values would affect the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Most operations or comparisons involving NULL result in NULL (which is a not "true" value in a boolean sense, but doesn't equal false either).

The most notable exceptions are:

- aggregate functions (such as sum, min, max, etc...) which generally ignore NULL values unless they are the only values fed to them
- functions and operators that are meant for specifically dealing with such values, like `IFNULL()`, `COALESCE()`, `x IS NULL`, `x <=> y`, etc...